# How to show video from wp option value?

Tags: categories

I am working on category page in admin section providing extra field. and following this code.Here is the link of code :-https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-category-extra-fields/

I am using two fields from the above link category image and extra field in extra field i have added youtube url.

I want to show video in my page using this code but not to get the video or any value in page. Here is my code:-

```
<?php 
//first get the current category ID
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
//then i get the data from the database
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

if (isset($cat_data['extra1'])){
//echo '<div class="category_image"><img src="'.$cat_meta['extra1'].'"></div>';
echo do_shortcode('[videojs youtube="'.$cat_meta['extra1'].'" width="699" height="269" preload="auto" loop="true" autoplay="false" controls="false" class="responsive-video"]');
}
?>
```

kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: Is that a typo? i.e. `$cat_data` and `$cat_meta`

Comment: Sorry what do mean?I can not understand what are you asking?

Comment: You assign `$cata_data`, but then check `$cat_meta`, so your `if` statement will always be false.

Comment: oh,yes let me check my code.

Comment: Yes it's my mistake, but when I echo extrafield value(echo $cat_meta['extra1'];) no value is return.and i checked db have video url in table.

Comment: Yes, you need to change `$cat_meta` to `$cat_data`.

Comment: I have changed but still have no value when i echo echo $cat_meta['extra1'];

Comment: Dude. Change `$cat_meta['extra1']` to `$cat_data['extra1']`. I can't make it any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

if ( isset($cat_data['extra1'] ) ){
    echo do_shortcode('[videojs youtube="'.$cat_meta['extra1'].'" width="699" height="269" preload="auto" loop="true" autoplay="false" controls="false" class="responsive-video"]');
}
```

There's a number of things you're not doing or could do better here:

- You never check if the option exists, if `get_option` doesn't find anything and returns a value of `false` your code may fatal error and crash
- You're relying on the `videojs` shortcode, but you can remove this dependency by using the oembed functionality that comes with WordPress. Did you know if you place a youtube URL in content on a line by itself, it's auto-magically converted into video player?
- You never check that the URL is indeed a URL, e.g. if the URL was: `"]<script>alert('hacked');</script>[sldfjknv attr="`, there's a chance this could result in unescaped insecure javascript running on the frontend
- If said plugin or shortcode isn't present the functionality will fail with no fallback
- It doesn't account for empty values or strings of spaces, "   " is not a valid youtube URL, but it is a valid string, and will generate an invalid shortcode
- If `$cat_id` is replaced with a variable that isn't a number it could have unexpected consequences, and is a possible route to sql injection

With this in mind, lets refactor:

```
$data = get_option( 'category_'.$cat_id );

// does the object exist?
if ( $data !== false ) {
    // empty checks if the value is set, and also checks if it has something in it, not just spaces
    if ( !empty( $data['extra1'] ) ) {
        $url = $data['extra1'];

        // URLs are URLs, lets escape this URL so that nothing nasty is passed along
        $url = esc_url( $url );

        // grab the embed html using oembed ( it has a second argument to specify width and height but it should be unnecessary )
        $embed = wp_oembed_get( $url );
        // set up a fallback
        if ( $embed != false ) {
            $embed = '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        }
        echo $embed;
    }
}
```

The new version checks the values are what they need to be, escapes the values, and uses the well tested WordPress Core APIs rather than a 3rd party. Responsiveness should be taken care of by your theme/plugins CSS. it also falls back to a hyperlink if the embed fails for whatever reason.